# Mongoose Web Server Config

Tags: mongoose-web-server

I'm using the binary version of Mongoose embedded web server (mongoose-free-6.4.exe) to test a small project locally. I noticed that all requests are sent with the following header:

`Content-Type: text/plain`

Is it possible to force all requests to configure this to UTF-8??

`Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

I was looking poking around and do we need to recompile any configuration change ? I was unable to find an easy way to do this. Did I misse something?

Comment: is mongoose binary the same as the source code library at cesanta.com? if i try cesanta.com/products/binary takes me to index, my book is talking about mongoose binary local server but cant quite understand if its the same product or binary is obsolete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the way to do this on `mongoose.conf`:

```
# Add your special mime types here 
m *.html=text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I couldn't find a way to configure the default one on the other hand. But I found this on Git with limited information:

https://github.com/cesanta/fossa/issues/238